# python multiprocessing.Process.terminate - How to kill child processes

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

This code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from threading import Thread
import subprocess
import time

class WorkerProcess(mp.Process):
  def run(self):
      # Simulate long running task
      self.subprocess = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-c', 'import time; time.sleep(1000)'])
      self.code = self.subprocess.wait()


class ControlThread(Thread):
  def run():
      jobs = []
      for _ in range(2):
          job = WorkerProcess()
          jobs.append(job)
          job.start()

      # wait for a while and then kill jobs
      time.sleep(2)
      for job in jobs:
          job.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    controller = ControlThread()
    controller.start()
```

When I terminate the spawned WorkerProcess instances. They die just fine, however the subprocesses `python -c 'import time; time.sleep(1000)` runs until completition. This is [well documented in the official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate), but how do I kill the child processes of a killed process?

A possbile soultion might be:

- Wrap WorkerProcess.run() method inside try/except block catching SIGTERM, and terminating the `subprocess.call call`. But I am not sure how to catch the SIGTERM in the WorkerProcess
- I also tried setting `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)` in the WorkerProcess, but I am getting ValuError, because it is allowed to be set only in the main thread.

What do I do now?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: As @svalorzen pointed out in comments this doesn't really work since the reference to `self.subprocess` is lost.

---

<s>Finally came to a clean, acceptable solution. Since mp.Process.terminate is a method, we can override it.</s>

```
class WorkerProcess(mp.Process):
    def run(self):
        # Simulate long running task
        self.subprocess = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-c', 'import time; time.sleep(1000)'])
        self.code = self.subprocess.wait()

    # HERE
    def terminate(self):
      self.subprocess.terminate()
      super(WorkerProcess, self).terminate()
```

Comment: For some reason I lose the `self.subprocess` field when I call the `terminate()` function, as in the class does not contain the field anymore (checked by printing `dir`). Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Strange.. I too got `AttributeError`, so I set `self.subprocess = None` in `WorkerProcess.__init__` (dont forget to call `super()`). With that in place I no longer get `AttributeError` but the value is `None` at all times: after starting and before terminating. However setting `self.bar = 42` in `WorkerProcess.__init__` works as expected (can be accessed at all times). I think this calls for a separate question (feel free to post a link if you ask it)

Comment: Yes, I found that out. But I guess this then makes no sense as an accepted answer, as it doesn't work. I assumed it worked since it sounded like you actually used this code to solve your problem, but if it doesn't..

Comment: It solved my problem of terminating the child process when terminating the parent, that's all I really cared about. Would you mind sharing why you need to access the `self.subprocess` in the first place?

Comment: I don't understand. In `terminate` you explicitly call `self.subprocess.terminate()`. Thus you are also accessing `self.subprocess`. I cannot call the `terminate` of the subprocess as the field does not exist in the `terminate` function of the worker, and you just said you have the same problem if I understood correctly. Thus, how can you terminate the child when you cannot call its terminate function?

Comment: I feel stupid now, you are absolutely correct. Sorry for the confusion! Unaccepted the answer. I think the trick to really solving this might be by using process groups, but I don't have the capacity to test it now

Comment: I have actually a working solution now. I simply add all subprocesses to a `Queue`, and if an interrupt is received I go over it and terminate everything (catching eventual errors for subprocesses that have already ended). It's not pretty but it works I guess..

Answer (score 1):

You can use queues to message to your subprocesses and ask them nicely to terminate their children before exiting themselves. You can't use signals in anywhere else but your main thread, so signals are not suitable for this.

Curiously, when I modify the code like this, even if I interrupt it with control+C, subprocesses will die as well. This may be OS related thing, though.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from threading import Thread
import subprocess
import time
from Queue import Empty


class WorkerProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self,que):
        super(WorkerProcess,self).__init__()
        self.queue = que

    def run(self):
        # Simulate long running task
        self.subprocess = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-c', 'import time; time.sleep(1000)'])
        while True:
            a = self.subprocess.poll()
            if a is None:
                time.sleep(1)
                try:
                    if self.queue.get(0) == "exit":
                        print "kill"
                        self.subprocess.kill()
                        self.subprocess.wait()
                        break
                    else:
                        pass
                except Empty:
                    pass
                print "run"
            else:
                print "exiting"


class ControlThread(Thread):

    def run(self):
        jobs = []
        queues = []
        for _ in range(2):
            q = mp.Queue()
            job = WorkerProcess(q)
            queues.append(q)
            jobs.append(job)
            job.start()

        # wait for a while and then kill jobs
        time.sleep(5)
        for q in queues:
            q.put("exit")
        time.sleep(30)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    controller = ControlThread()
    controller.start()
```

Hope this helps.

Hannu

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay and thanks for your answer, but I wanted to avoid using queues. As per the example terminating correctly you are right. This was just a dummy example just to ilustrate the workflow, which (idk why) works (unwisely chosen, I agree). In my real word case the process just kept running